# winsound.PlaySound() not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently I tried to implement a "Beep" sound to my code, I tried it with `winsound.Beep()`, but I have the beep disabled on my computer. Then i tried it with `winsound.PlaySound('Test.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME )`, but when I run the code I only hear the [windows background sound](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHtB0HWNaLQ) and not the actual sound.

Answer (score 0):

`winsound.PlaySound()` is always going to play *something*, unless you explicitly add the `SND_NODEFAULT` flag.  Your Test.wav file apparently doesn't exist in the current directory, or isn't in a format that Windows can read, so you're getting a default sound instead.